# Why does $rootScope binding work but calling $parent in child controller does not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I've got an app assigned to the `html` tag like this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="pieShopApp">
```

Which has the route of `/pies` and uses the `mainCtrl`:

```
when('/pies', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/pie-list.php',
    controller: 'mainCtrl'
}).
```

And in the `mainCtrl` I run this block of code to check for authentication changes in Firebase:

```
Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    //Doesn't work
    $scope.authData = authData; 
    //Works
    $rootScope.authData = authData;
});
```

Assigning the `logout` button another controller which handles the logout (this snippet assumes that `$scope` is being used, not `$rootScope`:

```
<div id="site-access-features">
    <a href="#/pies/register">
        <button id="register-btn" class="btn">Register</button>
    </a>
    <a href="#/pies/login">
    <button ng-hide="$parent.authData" <!-- doesn't work when using $scope --> id="login-btn" class="btn">Log in</button>
    </a>
    <a href="#/pies/login">
    <button ng-controller="logoutCtrl" ng-show="$parent.authData" <!-- doesn't work when using $scope -->id="logout-btn" class="btn" ng-click="logout()">Log out</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now, in the `mainCtrl` I have to use `$rootScope` to be able to access the `authData` in the `ng-show="authData"` since I  have assigned a new controller to the `logout` button. Why is this? I thought since the `logout` button is still inside of the `mainCtrl`'s `$scope` I would be able to use `$parent.authData` in the markup to access the `mainCtrl`'s `$scope` but it's not working.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Normally, auth data is needed across your app to verify access. In this case, it's not a bad practice to use $rootScope.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
"authData"//is on the $rootScope
```

instead of:

```
"$parent.authData"
```

Since you have:

```
$rootScope.authData = authData;
```

Comment: Well I know that. But if I would have $scope it doesn't work with $parent, think I forgot to change it in the code. Is it best practice here to use rootscope anyways?